# Aggregate multiple rows to one row, then select which values go to which column SQL

Tags: sql, conditional-statements, aggregate

I have a table that looks as follows:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | ABC1 |  | 2904 |  | def |
| 2 | ABC | ABC2 |  | 2400 | 504 | ghi |
| 3 | ABC | ABC3 |  | 504 | 504 | jkl |

which needs to be aggregated into one row, looking like this:

| col1 | col2 | col3 | col4 | col5 | col6 | col7 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ABC | ABC1 | 2904 | 2400 | 504 | def |

I understand that it needs to be grouped based on col2. But then what SQL syntax do I need to say that:

- value of col3 for lowest col1 value stays in col3
- value of col5 for lowest col1 value goes to col4
- value of col5 for second col1 value stays in col5
- value of col5 for highest col1 value goes to col6
- value of col7 for lowest col1 value stays in col7

Comment: Can you share your best coding attempt at this problem for better troubleshooting?

Answer (score 0):

Think of this as three different select statements which isolate your min, max and secondary values from Col1. e.g. Select...Where Col1 = 1 (or whatever the min value is), Select...Where Col1 = 2, Select...Where Col1 = max.

Once you have those values broken out you can join all of them together and use the appropriate columns.

I chose to use min, max and row_number in the sub-query because I wasn't sure if your min is always 1 and your secondary value is always 2. If they are, you could write this a bit differently.

```
select 
    max(Case When a.col1 = mn.MinCol1 Then  a.col1 End) as NewCol1
    ,max(Case When a.col1 = mn.MinCol1 Then  a.col2 End) as NewCol2
    ,max(Case When a.col1 = mn.MinCol1 Then  a.col3 End) as NewCol3
    ,max(Case When a.col1 = mn.MinCol1 Then  a.col5 End) as NewCol4
    ,max(Case When a.col1 = sec.SecondCol1 Then  a.col5 End) as NewCol5
    ,max(Case When a.col1 = mx.MaxCol1 Then  a.col5 End) as NewCol6
    ,max(Case When a.col1 = mn.MinCol1 Then  a.col7 End) as NewCol7
FROM AggTable a
--Get Min Values (Grouped By col2)
LEFT JOIN (Select 
                min(col1) as MinCol1 
                ,col2
          From AggTable
          Group By 
                col2
          ) mn on a.col1 = mn.MinCol1 and a.col2 = mn.col2
--Get Max Values (Grouped By col2)
LEFT JOIN (Select 
                max(col1) as MaxCol1 
                ,col2
            From AggTable
            Group By
                col2
            ) mx on a.col1 = mx.MaxCol1 and a.col2 = mx.col2 
--Get Second Value (Grouped By col2)
LEFT JOIN (select 
            row_number() OVER(Order By col1) as RowNumber
            ,col1  as SecondCol1
            ,col2
          From AggTable
          Group By
                col1
                ,col2
                ) sec on a.col1 = sec.SecondCol1 and a.col2 = sec.col2 and sec.RowNumber = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option is using window functions, given that your DBMS allow them, whereas:

- `FIRST_VALUE` is in charge of gathering the first value of "*col3*" by ordering on "*col1*"
- `LEAD` is in charge of gathering the consecutive values of "*col5*" by ordering on "*col1*".

Then you retrieve only the first row with the `LIMIT 1` clause.

```
SELECT col1,
       col2,
       FIRST_VALUE(col3) OVER(ORDER BY col1) AS col3,
       col5                                  AS col4,
       LEAD(col5, 1) OVER(ORDER BY col1)     AS col5,
       LEAD(col5, 2) OVER(ORDER BY col1)     AS col6,
       col7
FROM tab
LIMIT 1
```